# Compile all CPP files using makefile under MinGW

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, gnu-make

The directory structure of my C++ project is

```
/..
   makefile     <- the makefile is in root
   /include     <- subdirectory that has to be included while compiling
   /obj         <- target place for all *.o and final executable
   /src         <- sources
```

And my current makefile is:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++11

INC=-Iinclude
SRC=src
TGT=obj

all: myapp

myapp: myapp.o
    $(CC) $(TGT)/myapp.o -o $(TGT)/myapp

myapp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) $(SRC)/myapp.cpp -o $(TGT)/myapp.o

clean:
    rm -rf $(TGT)
    mkdir $(TGT)
```

This worked for my first file. I am a total makefile novice - please help me compile all files under the `/src` directory and link them to an executable in `/obj` directory.

the makefile has to work under Windows, I am using MinGW and MSYS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a list of your source files:

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
```

and a list of corresponding object files:

```
OBJS = $(addprefix $(TGT)/, $(notdir $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)))
```

and the target executable:

```
$(TGT)/myapp: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@
```

The rule for building the objects:

```
$(TGT)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Now you must specify are the options for g++:

```
INCLUDES = -Iinclude
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11 $(INCLUDES)
```

And everything together:

```
SRC=src
TGT=obj
INCLUDES = -Iinclude
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11 $(INCLUDES)
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
OBJS = $(addprefix $(TGT)/, $(notdir $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)))

$(TGT)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TGT)/myapp: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@
```

It is important, that in front of `$(CXX) ...` there must be a "tab" character, not spaces.

Comment: Can the `-Idir` part be parametrized? Your solution seems concise. Two things to change though: the make-script should place both the `*.o` and the final executable in the TGT directory...

Comment: What do you mean with parameterized? You can put it in a separate variable and add this variable to `CXXFLAGS`, of course. See modified answer.

Comment: @elmes Please try the modified `Makefile`, I adjusted for the separate target directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`VPATH` for separating source and object files](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search):

```
src/myapp.c
obj/Makefile
```

Take your existing `Makefile`, move it into `obj/`, omit references to `$(TGT)` and `$(SRC)` and add the following:

```
VPATH=../src
```

Note that if you are trying to do [multi-architecture builds, `VPATH` is not ideal](http://mad-scientist.net/make/vpath.html).

---

BTW, you're not capitalizing on [builtin rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules).  Where you have

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++11
myapp: myapp.o
    $(CC) $(TGT)/myapp.o -o $(TGT)/myapp

myapp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) $(SRC)/myapp.cpp -o $(TGT)/myapp.o
```

you could instead use:

```
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -std=c++11
CXXFLAGS+=$(INC)
LDLIBS+=-lstdc++

myapp: myapp.o
```

---

So, to sum it all up, your new `obj/Makefile` should look like this:

```
VPATH=../src
INC=-I../include
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -std=c++11
CXXFLAGS+=$(INC)
LDLIBS+=-lstdc++

myapp: myapp.o
```

You can create another `Makefile` up from `obj/` to recurse down into this new one, if necessary:

```
all: obj/myapp

obj/myapp:
    mklink obj/Makefile ../Makefile
    $(MAKE) --directory=obj/
```

Comment: as I said, I am new to makefiles. Could you create a working example that fits the scenario described in the question?

Comment: ok, the only thing missing from the example was the VPATH.  So there you go.

Comment: but why does the makefile has to reside in the `obj` dir.. it's not a good place to keep it, since I want to easily clear that directory

Comment: You can create a symlink in `obj/` to the Makefile (using `mklink`) at build time.

Comment: *shrug* seems simple enough to me, but I'd leave the `obj/` directory intact so that it would be simpler still.